# Classic Image problem

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, electric-fields, charge, conductors

The classic image problem:

Here, to calculate the potential above an infinite grounded conducting plate and a point charge q held at distance d above the plate, the image method is used.

Here, I want to know, why the grounded plate is taken? What does it signify?  And if the charge q is placed above the infinite grounded conducting plate, then doesn't it induce the opposite charge on the infinite plate?

Answer (score 0):

Potentials $\phi(x,y,z)$ are only defined up to an arbitrary  constant, so $ \phi(x,y,z)$ and $\phi(x,y,z)+3$ are equivalent. ``Grounded'' simply means that we have fixed the constant by making  $\phi=0$ on the plate.  For a point change $+q$, the total charge indiced on the plate is $-q$.